# No bucket found for "host.docker.internal"

Tags: javascript, aws, amazon-s3

como puedo acceder a la máquina host desde una imagen docker?, llevo un rato con esto y no puedo

pasa esto.

Estoy simulado AWS S3 localmente via serverless-s3-local, el cual funciona bien, me premite hacer todas las operaciones, es decir subir y descargar archivos, hasta alli todo bien

pero quiero consumir esta instancia de S3 desde `AWS SAM` el cual corre dentro de docker he intentado con el mismo localhost, pero no funciona, he intentado con IP, tampoco

```
const s3 = new S3({
  forcePathStyle: true,
  endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint("http://host.docker.internal:4569"),
  region: "local",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: "S3RVER",
    secretAccessKey: "S3RVER",
  },
});
```

con `http://host.docker.internal` me arroja este error

```
Server ready: http://localhost:3000 
error: No bucket found for "host.docker.internal"
info: GET / 404 13ms -
```

tengo todo corriendo en la misma máquina host, es decir, Docker, S3, SAM, Serverless, etc

pero `AWS SAM` no puede consumir nada de mi máquina host, serverless-s3 esta en la máquina host de docker, como puedo acceder a ello?

Comment: Puedes indicar como has levantado tu contenedor y en qué tipo de SO estas corriendo docker?

Comment: SO es windows, levanto el contenedor via docker compose